# AngularJS: Behavior of $valid in Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, cross-browser

I'm currently working on a custom validation directive. It runs smoothly on Firefox but then I decided to test it on Chrome and IE and wondered why it won't work on either of them.

After adding some debug outputs I noticed a strange behavior.
When selecting and unselecting the checkbox on Firefox I get following output:

```
 Object { $viewValue=true, $modelValue=true, $parsers=[2], mehr...}
 valid: true
 Object { $viewValue=false, $modelValue=false, $parsers=[2], mehr...}
 valid: false
```

On Chrome on the other hand I get following output:

```
 Constructor {$viewValue: undefined, $modelValue: false, $parsers: Array[2], $formatters: Array[2], $viewChangeListeners: Array[0]…}
 valid: false
 Constructor {$viewValue: true, $modelValue: true, $parsers: Array[2], $formatters: Array[2], $viewChangeListeners: Array[0]…}
 valid: true
```

The $viewValue is undefined upon the first invocation. It then behaves as if inverted for some reason.
Does anyone know the reason for this behavior and a possible solution for it?

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("gewinnspielApp").directive("customValidity", function() {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            customText: "@customValidity",
        },
        require: "?ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element[0].setCustomValidity(scope.customText);
            element.bind("change", function() {
                console.log(ngModel);
                console.log("valid: " + ngModel.$valid);
                element[0].setCustomValidity((ngModel.$valid ? "" : scope.customText));             
            });
        }
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<td style="border:none; padding-right: 4px; width: 10px;">
    <input id="tnc" name="tnc" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="formData.tnc" required data-ng-class="{'ng-dirty': submitted, 'ng-pristine': !submitted}" data-custom-validity="Bitte akzeptieren Sie die Nutzungsbedingungen.">
</td>
```

Edit:
Looks like a problem with the model update and change listener. When I add `{{ myForm.tnc.$valid }}` in the HTML page, the value matches the expected outcome.

Comment: do you initialize `$scope.tnc` somewhere? If not, it may indeed be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, I suspect some browser difference with input initialization and model updates. To suppress this, take care of the following:

You bind your checkbox to `$scope.tnc` but didn't supply any code where that may be initialized.
If you have a controller for that view please try setting `$scope.tnc = false;` in the beginning.

If for some reason you don't use a controller here you could also try adding an initialization expression in the view, like so:

```
<input id="tnc" name="tnc" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="tnc" data-ng-init="tnc = false" [...]>
```

Update: Ok, since the model initialization difference is out of question now, maybe this will help you with the view state inconsistencies: [the ngChecked directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Attach it to your checkbox input and evaluate the expression on your checkbox value model variable.

Comment: I edited my model in the question. It's part of a formData which is initialized with false. The problem seems to be the $valid expression on the input element not the model.